# How to call 2 digit phone number in IOS 6 7 8 using tel links

Tags: ios, html, mobile, tel

**I wonder why 2 digit phone number won't open phone app after tapping "call"**

```
<a href="tel:555">555</a> // shows alert, tap on call opens phone app

<a href="tel:55">55</a>  // shows alert, tap on call won't open app
```

Comment: its just how they defined it.

Comment: what about calling emergency numbers in some countries ? lets just ignore that ...

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't possible using the `tel` scheme, then Apple's implementation doesn't conform to [RFC2806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt) (which they reference [in their documentation for `Phone Links`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html)), which states:

> It should also be noted that implementations MUST NOT assume that telephone numbers have a maximum, minimum or fixed length, or that they would always begin with a certain number.  Implementors are encouraged to familiarize themselves with the international standards.

I'd file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think 2 digit phone numbers are functional numbers. Apple does not allow you to call numbers shorter than 3 digits.

Comment: what about emergency numbers?

Comment: users have to type that manually into their dialer.  I don't know if the US has 2 digit emergency numbers.

Comment: Apple may not support per locale numbers.  They may default to US options.  Looks like web pages can not directly link to 2 digit numbers, users must dial them in themselves.

Answer (score 0):

According to spec, a valid telephone number should consist of the first digit of the area code being between 2 and 9, followed by at least 2 digits.  Therefore, the smallest valid telephone number is at least 3 digits long.

If your attempting to do something like dial a number, and then dial an extension you can define a pause with `p` like this:

```
tel:234p55
```

`w` can also be used to specify a wait-for-dialtone.

---

I do not know if this will work or not but you may be able to dial a 2 digit number using `phone-context`

```
<a href="tel:55;phone-context=+234">55</a>
```